# CMake Generator Expression not recognized by Ninja

Tags: cmake, ninja, generator-expression, cmake-modules

I was trying to use a CMake Generator Expression such as:

```
 $<TARGET_GENEX_EVAL:foo,$<TARGET_PROPERTY:$<TARGET_NAME_IF_EXISTS:foo>,PROP_BAR>>
```

This expression works fine when the Generator used is Visual Studio or Unix Makefiles but fails when the generator used is Ninja with errors such as:

```
CMake Error at cmake/<fname>.cmake:629 (add_custom_command):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

$<TARGET_GENEX_EVAL:foo,$<TARGET_PROPERTY:$<TARGET_NAME_IF_EXISTS:foo>,PROP_BAR>>

  Expression did not evaluate to a known generator expression
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/<fname>.cmake:1269
  <target>/CMakeLists.txt:16
```

Does Ninja not support Generator Expressions?

If it doesn't what are my best options?

If it does, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Can you show the whole `add_custom_command`?

Comment: @KamilCuk it is something along the lines,   ```add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${dictionary}.cxx ${arg1} ${arg2} ${arg3} COMMAND ${command} -v2 -f  ${dictionary}.cxx ${arg4} ... more args)```

Comment: arg4 here is set using the generator expression I mentioned above.Also, the same command works fine if generator is Unix Makefiles/ Visual Studio